# How to find the value of the angle gamma in a diagram where lines intersect?

Tags: geometry

In this figure $BC$ bisect angle $OCD$. What is the value of $\gamma$?

[image: Sketch of the problem]

What I tried so far is below:

[image: Sketch of the attempt]

But that's how far I reached. What is missing in my attempt?. An answer which would help me can include some theoretical basis in these kind of situations. What to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Focus on $\triangle BCD$.  $\gamma=\angle BCD+\angle BDC=20^\circ/2+25^\circ=35^\circ$

Comment: Keep in mind that $\angle BCD \neq 20$ instead $\angle OCD = 20^o$ Can you please take a closer inspection of the problem?. The answer you propose is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Oh, sorry for my careless mistake and my delayed response.  I was working on a probability problem.  I hope the story of [Grothendieck's prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)#In_mathematics) will cheer you up despite the difficulty that you've experienced in doing math.

Comment: It seems my answer check up with what you got. I also reached $35^{o}$ but to do so I had to go back to my book and find a bisector is characterized by dividing in two halves an angle. I forgot about that. The rest where there is a $120^{o}$ is rather distraction or confusing, not sure why is it there. But there is a property which does seem to link an angle in that position.Am I correct?. By the way, I dont get the story of Grothendieck's prime.Does it mean that he gave a random number as an answer to somebody who just asked about something?.Does it mean he was just being mean?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell I just want to say that even mathematicians can make mistakes, but they may indicate us a way to solve the problem.

Comment: @@ChrisSteinbeckBell The number $120^\circ$ is unrelated to the calculations.  Such reflex angle exists has legitimate reason to exist though.  Since this is about *polygons*, it's better that the sides form a closed loop.  There might be another question (of similar type, but wth slight or no modifiions in numbers given) with $AC$ being a straight line in another book.  Due to copyright, I imagine that he/she may want to change the figure a bit.

Comment: Ok got it. But I'm curious about that $120^{o}$ I remember there was an identity which versed about angles in those position. Can you help me to understand that part?. In other words (although this is not part of the problem) can we relate $120^{o}$ with other angles in that figure?

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell Given that all other angles are fixed as in the question body, $\angle AOC=120^\circ$ only affects $\angle OAB$.Math is not a spectator sport.According to the Hungarian mathematician Palm Halmos, [*don't just read it; fight it!*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Paul_Halmos).You won't understand the identity that you want $(n-2)\times180^\circ$=sum of interior angles of a $n$-sided polygon unless you tried it yourself and tell us where you got stuck in case of failure.  It's useless in writing reflex $\angle AOC=120^\circ+\angle OAB+\gamma+0.5\angle OCD=(4-2)\times180^\circ$.